# Debugging xsp on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mono, xsp

Is it possible to debug a website running under xsp on windows?
I would like to attach to the process from visual studio if that is possible.

I modified my xsp2.bat file to enable debuging
@"C:\PROGRA~1\Mono-2.4\bin\mono.exe" --debug=mdb-optimizations "C:\PROGRA~1\Mono-2.4\lib\mono\2.0\winhack\xsp2.exe" %*

but it doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can't do this, mono-debug is linux only..
(there's even no mdb.exe in the %Program Files/Mono-2.4/bin folder)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this functionality is coming soon from Novell.  [Mono Tools For Visual Studio](http://visualstudiohacks.com/blog/visual-studio-and-mono-at-teched/).

Comment: I am looking forward to that!

Answer (score 0):

As balint points out, the mdb debugger is Linux only. However, you should be able to use the [SoftDebugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Sdb).